# Eclipse rename element keyboard shortcut

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have written an Eclipse View that displays a tree of elements.

How can I hook into the standard Eclipse "Rename - Refactoring" keyboard shortcut so that when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> with an element of my tree selected I can handle renaming that element?

I think I might need to use one of the LTK extension points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct code:

```
IActionBars actionBars = getViewSite().getActionBars();
actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.RENAME.getId(), new Action()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    ISelection viewSelection = viewer.getSelection();
    if (viewSelection instanceof IStructuredSelection)
    {
      IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)viewSelection;
      Object o = selection.getFirstElement();

      ....
    }
  }
});
```

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_hook_into_global_actions,_such_as_Copy_and_Delete%3F